# Options for Automated ANTLR grammar Documentation

Tags: java, antlr4, documentation-generation

We have a custom domain specific language that we are planning to make open to the public and since our interpreter in ANTLR we are planning to make the grammar file open and take feature requests on Github. What options are there to automate the documentation of the grammar file automated (or alternative that we can use here). Though the idea is that we make the entire grammar easy to understand I believe additional documentation is necessary. So I would like to know how everyone else is doing this or are there any other options I can go for.

Comment: Documentation you can generate is *totally useless* documentation. It's no better than nonsense code like `int x = 42; // assign 42 to x`. Just add some comments to the grammar file, but only in the places where you feel it adds *real* value.

Comment: Thanks for that. How exactly do you document it ? Each and every rule and extended descriptions or some thing like that ? Or do you just assume that anyone reading the grammar can get a hang of it. Thanks a lot for you input.

Comment: Well, I usually make sure the rule names are very clear, and try to keep the rules themselves simple enough not to need documentation. And indeed, I assume that when you touch grammar-related things then you know what you're doing :) Of course, this is only my opinion.

Comment: Damn that means I have to include an entire ANTLR guide too. I think I will also keep the generated parser and lexer along with the grammar then. That seems the only way in which I can avoid the entire hassle,